# How to fix the artifacts in the hair of the subject of this photo?

Tags: post-processing, retouching

How can I fix the edges of her hair?

http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/6499/onionmodel2.jpg

Comment: I've never seen such an artifact from a still photo. How was that picture taken? Normally, a photo strait out of a camera won't have such artifacts, so you wouldn't need to fix them.

Comment: Looks like a bad Photoshop job on the hair. You can't really fix it. This might fit better over at the graphic design stack exchange if you really want to get detailed into how to recreate the missing hair.

Comment: This has nothing to do with photography. The pixelization that you see looks like a poor keying job to me. The photo was probably fine.

Comment: Plus, her face is out of focus, the front sleeve is sharp.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bad mask to me. Regardless, no fixing it in its current state. Unless you're a good artist and want to draw hair extensions...

Answer (score 2):

I would not even try, you can fix it but it will take a lot of time. Even for me with a lot of Photoshop experience. You would have you rebuild the hair, and delete a lot of it.

Request a better photo, or even just the original one - this one seems to have been tutored in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Find a stock image of a red lady over the white background and use parts of her hair to patch the image you are trying to fix. You will need to grade color a little bit and it will take like 10-15 minutes of work, but certainly doable.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a fuzzy select of the outer hair and then try different blur settings.